# Solving general system of equations

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find the closed form solution to a general system of equations. 
The number of equations and variables is `C`. How do I specify the system of equations?

If I use `Solve`, I can solve a system of equations with a fixed number of variables. What should I do if the number of equations and variables is not fixed.

The equations are of the form:

$p_i = q_i + o_{i0}p_0 + o_{i1}p_1 + \cdots + o_{iC-1}p_{C-1}$

for $ i = 0$ to $C-1$

I tried doing

```
Solve[{p[j] == q[j] + sum[o[j, i]*p[i], {i, 0, C - 1}]}, {p[j]}]
```

but I am not getting any output.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: People here generally like users to post Mathematica code, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.

Comment: I dont know how to specify a variable number of equations in mathematica as well :(

Comment: Where exactly did your system of equations come from? Are they algebraic or transcendental?

Comment: algebraic. I have a continuous time two dimensional markov chain with a general number of states. I want to find the stationary distribution.

Comment: You mean something like $\sum_i^n a_{(i,k)} x^i = b$ with $n$ and $k$ unknown?

Comment: @rhermans something similar. It is a linear equation though, of the form AX=B where A is an nxn matrix with n unknown

Comment: Do you know how to reformulate your problem into matrix form?

Comment: @J.M it can be done on paper, but can we specify a matrix with a generic number of rows and columns in mathematica?